# SQL - Making columns values as column headers for multiple values

Tags: sql, pivot

I have the following table

| ID | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | vertical | auto |
| 1 | subvertical | tires |
| 1 | company uid | 54321 |
| 1 | auto debit | true |
| 2 | vertical | healthcare |
| 2 | subvertical | dentist |
| 2 | company uid | 12345 |
| 2 | auto debit | false |

The output I would like is to use the values in column key as column headers with values from column value. Meaning I would like to see:

| ID | vertical | subvertical | company uid | auto debit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | auto | tires | 54321 | true |
| 2 | healthcare | dentist | 12345 | false |

I've tried achieving this with the following query:

```
SELECT payment_intent_id 
       MAX CASE WHEN key = 'podium_location_uid' 
                THEN value END AS "Podium Location UID" 
       MAX CASE WHEN key = 'payment_method_type' 
                THEN value END AS "Payment Method Type" 
       MAX CASE WHEN key = 'customer_name' 
                THEN value END AS "Customer Name" 
       MAX CASE WHEN key = 'sub_vertical' 
                THEN value END AS "Sub Vertical" 
       MAX CASE WHEN key = 'vertical' THEN value END AS "Vertical" 
FROM payment_intents_metadata 
GROUP BY payment_intent_id
```

but I'm getting the following error:

> Malformed query: line 2:6: mismatched input 'case'. Expecting: ',', 'EXCEPT', 'FETCH', 'FROM', 'GROUP', 'HAVING', 'INTERSECT', 'LIMIT', 'OFFSET', 'ORDER', 'UNION', 'WHERE',

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: can you share your latest coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: select payment_intent_id
 max case when key = 'podium_location_uid' then value end AS "Podium Location UID"
 max case when key = 'payment_method_type' then value end AS "Payment Method Type"
 max case when key = 'customer_name' then value end AS "Customer Name"
 max case when key = 'sub_vertical' then value end AS "Sub Vertical"
 max case when key = 'vertical' then value end AS "Vertical"
from payment_intents_metadata
group by payment_intent_id

Comment: This is the last thing I tried, however I received this error "Malformed query: line 2:6: mismatched input 'case'. Expecting: ',', 'EXCEPT', 'FETCH', 'FROM', 'GROUP', 'HAVING', 'INTERSECT', 'LIMIT', 'OFFSET', 'ORDER', 'UNION', 'WHERE', <EOF>

Comment: What RDMS are you using? Your query doesn't look like valid SQL to me...

Answer (score 1):

The query you posted has lots of syntax errors -- here is how I would write it

```
SELECT payment_intent_id, 
       MAX (CASE WHEN key = 'podium_location_uid' THEN value END) AS "Podium Location UID", 
       MAX (CASE WHEN key = 'payment_method_type' THEN value END) AS "Payment Method Type",
       MAX (CASE WHEN key = 'customer_name'       THEN value END) AS "Customer Name",
       MAX (CASE WHEN key = 'sub_vertical'        THEN value END) AS "Sub Vertical",
       MAX (CASE WHEN key = 'vertical'            THEN value END) AS "Vertical" 
FROM payment_intents_metadata 
GROUP BY payment_intent_id
```

> Please note the use of `(`,`)`, and `,`

Answer (score 0):

You either have a version of SQL I've never seen before, or your query is terribly formatted and a basic SQL tutorial should be looked up.

```
SELECT payment_intent_id, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN key = 'podium_location_uid' 
                THEN value END) AS "Podium Location UID", 
       MAX(CASE WHEN key = 'payment_method_type' 
                THEN value END) AS "Payment Method Type", 
       MAX(CASE WHEN key = 'customer_name' 
                THEN value END) AS "Customer Name", 
       MAX(CASE WHEN key = 'sub_vertical' 
                THEN value END) AS "Sub Vertical", 
       MAX(CASE WHEN key = 'vertical' 
                THEN value END) AS "Vertical" 
FROM payment_intents_metadata 
GROUP BY payment_intent_id
```